# Why does prop('outerHTML') strip events, and how can I prevent it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
const continueButton = $("<button>Doesn't work.</button>").click(() => {alert("hello")});
$(".content").append(continueButton.prop('outerHTML'));          
$(".content").append ($("<button>Works.</button>").click(() => {alert("hello")}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

The reason I'm asking this question is because I need to pass the string version of some HTML to a function. For that reason, I can't use .append. but when i use the code above, it seems that the click event no longer works.

How can I get the HTML as a string, but have the click event still work?

---

More context: I am using a library that expects me to add HTML to it as a string. But I want to add HTML with a button on it that functions when it's clicked. I'm using jQuery to create the HTML, but when I try to pass the HTML string to the library, the buttons don't function.

Comment: You can't. Event listeners are attached to DOM nodes, there's no way to represent them in HTML strings.

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) instead of linking to jsfiddle.

Comment: By mapping the event listeners into globally-accessible functions and using inline event attribute text to call such .. the functions can be tucked it a tidy space and anonymized, as long as the names remain accessible. Probably X vs Y’ish. $(“.content”).attr(“onclick”; “return my_globally_reachable_func(event);”)

Comment: @user2864740 I added more context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delegate the event to the content element and use `button` as target selector

```js
// add delegated event listener before inserting buttons
$('.content').on('click', 'button', (e) => console.log($(e.target).text()))

const continueButton = $("<button>Doesn't work.</button>");
$(".content").append(continueButton.prop('outerHTML'))
             .append ("<button>Works.</button>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

Comment: the thing is, I'm using a third-party library to add the event to the button. Is there any way I can take that working button and inspect it in the HTML to figure out what event is firing? There's a good chance the function is already there and ready to call. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: In the element inspector you can look for a little tag beside elements labeled "event" and see what that tells you. For example in this demo the tag is beside the content element

Comment: unfortunately, the code has been minified. I'll figure out some way

Answer (score 2):

In line 1 the object has an event attached to it but this isn't reflected in HTML. Therefore when you add the `outerHTML` to an element, the browser creates a new element but events are not defined in the HTML so they don't exist.

If you embed the script inside the button HTML then it will work when you apply this HTML in different places: `$('<button onclick="alert(\'hello\');">Test</button>')`.